# Redirect work only first time

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Trying to make a redirect from this url:

```
http://www.mywebsite.it/it/component/fss/?view=admin_support
```

to this url:

```
http://www.mywebsite.it/it/index.php/component/fss/?view=admin_support
```

I made a .htaccess file with this code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/it/component/fss/?$ /it/index.php/component/fss/
```

All work if i click for the first time on the url. The url began **/it/index.php/component** but if i click into another link on the page ( like http://www.mywebsite.it/it/component/fss/?view=list ) i'm redirecting to the website home page.

But if i copy the address ( http://www.mywebsite.it/it/component/fss/?view=admin_support ) and i paste into another tab, the redirect work.

How i can solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mod_rewrite` rules instead of `RedirectMatch` to match query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+it/(component/fss/?)\?view=[^&\s]+[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /it/index.php/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: I have try your code but the result is the same with RedirectMatch

Comment: In my .htaccess there are only your rule. I have try on chrome with private window and clear all my cookie and if i go on the url can have `?view=admin_support` the redirect work to index.php, but if i go into another ulr, can have for example `?view=test` the redirect don't work. I have try remove the view fro m your rule but all stop work. How i can made alla page have `it/component/fss/` redirect to `/it/index.php/component/fss`? My .htaccess is on the first forlder ( httpdocs ). Thanks @anubhava

Comment: Yes. Only the pages that have `/it/component/fss/` to `/it/index.php/component/fss`.

Comment: I got error 500. The url change from `http://www.mywebsite.it/it/component/fss/?view=admin` to `http://www.mywebsite.it/it/index.php/component/fss/?view=?view=admin%20HTTP/1.0`. Thank for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137526/discussion-between-anubhava-and-andrea-php).

Comment: All work, but the POST not. It work only GET, how i can made POST make a call with the /index.php/ ???

Comment: Actually POST requests must not be redirected otherwise you will loose POST data. I will update it to ignore POST requests

Comment: Thank you. There aren't a method to change the FORM action without edit the php code?

Comment: No unfortunately there is none because POST data gets lost in redirection

Answer (score 0):

Try to with a private window:

[image]

If it works, you need just to clear your browser cache.